# regarding O(n^2logn)

Tags: big-o

```
void function(int n ) {
    int i, j , k ;
    for ( i = n/2 ; i <= n ; i ++) 
        for ( j = 1; j + n/2 <= n; j++ ) 
            for ( k = 1; k <=n ; k = k*2 )
                count ++;
}
```

outer loop executes n/2 time,
middle loop executes n/2 time and
inner llop executes logn time.

complexity of the above function is O(n^2logn), but how will n/2 and n/2 will become n^2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The loops are nested, so all of their counts multiply. (n/2) * (n/2) is n^2 / 4, but constants don't matter to big-O; n^2 / 4 = O(n^2) and is written as such.

Answer (score 0):

For Big O notation, constants are omitted:  "If f(x) is a product of several factors, any constants (terms in the product that do not depend on x) are omitted."

So your inner loop is logn, your middle and outer loops are n/2, but together that's (n/2) * (n/2) * logn = 1/4 (n^2logn), and the 1/4 is discarded to give O(n^2logn).

Reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_oh_notation

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm's exact number of iterations, and its order of growth complexity are to be inferred like the following:

[image]

Supporting Document: [here](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt)